# Check LocalStorage Value

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to check if a special value is in the key like:

```
    if(localStorage.getItem('choice') == "simple")
    {       
        arrayname= simple.slice(); 

    }        
    else if (localStorage.getItem('choice') == "middle")
    {
        arrayname= middle.slice();

    }        
    else
    {
        arrayname= difficult.slice();

    }
```

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: if(localStorage[val])

Comment: Simply `if(value in localStorage)`. `if(localStorage[val])` will return an incorrect result if the value is an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's [dive into html5](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html):

> Like other JavaScript objects, you can treat the localStorage object as an associative array. Instead of using the getItem() and setItem() methods, you can simply use square brackets. For example, this snippet of code:

```
var foo = localStorage.getItem("bar");
// ...
localStorage.setItem("bar", foo);
```

> …could be rewritten to use square bracket syntax instead:

```
var foo = localStorage["bar"];
// ...
localStorage["bar"] = foo;
```

So you can do something like this:

```
if(localStorage['choice'] == "simple")
{       
    //...
}        
else if (localStorage['choice'] == "middle")
{
    //...
}        
else
{
    //...
}
```